# Is $\lfloor \log(n!)\rfloor \alpha$ equidistributed on the unit circle?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ergodic-theory

In this question $\lfloor a\rfloor$ means the greatest integer not exceeding $a$.

Using van der Corput's inequalities one is able to show that $\log(n!)\alpha$ is equidistributed on the unit circle ($\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$) for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

I am however having trouble trying to show that $\lfloor\log(n!)\rfloor\alpha$ is equidistributed on the unit circle for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. The reason I believe this result to hold is due to the research [here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/11742669_Ergodic_theorems_along_sequences_and_Hardy_fields), showing that $\lfloor\log(n!)\rfloor$ is a good sequence for mean $L^{2}$ convergence. Any ideas of how one could try and prove this would be much appreciated.

I suppose the more general question is: "Are there any results or methods that help in proving equidistribution (or good sequences for mean $L^{2}$ convergence) for functions that are rounded down?"

Comment: Could you replace the vertical bars with $ \lfloor\dots\rfloor $ floor signs to make the notation more recognizable?

Comment: Or with $[\dots]$ for those of us a little less hip.

Comment: @ZsbánAmbrus: done.

Comment: Would you agree to explain why $\log(n!)\alpha$ equidistributed?

Comment: @Lior I am afraid in the end I only ended up using $n^{1-\varepsilon}\log(n)$ is equidisitrbuted for all $1>\varepsilon > 0$, which is easy to prove (probably doesn't help you). The reason I believed $\log(n!)$ was equidistributed was due to an exercise in [link](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M259.02/vdc.pdf), I hope the link helps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. This follows from Theorem 3.2 of my [paper](http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/aquas/papers/paper18.pdf) with Michael Boshernitzan, Gregori Kolesnik and Máté Wierdl, 'Ergodic Averaging Sequences'.